# Javascript Putting images next to search results

Tags: javascript

I'm tring to put a image next to my search results in javascript:

My goal:

[image]

This is what it got so far:

[image]

This is my javascipt code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input#autocomplete').autocomplete({
        source: source,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            window.location.href = ui.item.value;
        },
    });
});


var source = [
    {
        value: 'bitcoin.html',
        label: 'Bitcoin (BTC)',
    },
];
```

HTML:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="searchbar">
            <div class="searchbar">
                <input type="search" id="autocomplete" placeholder="Search..."/>
                <button class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

After editing the source array
Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input#autocomplete').autocomplete({
        image: image,
        source: source,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            window.location.href = ui.item.value;
        },
    });
});

//Altcoin list
var source = [
    {
        image: 'http://via.placeholder.com/15x15'
        value: 'bitcoin.html',
        label: 'Bitcoin (BTC)',
    },
];
```

HTML:

```
<div class="searchbar">
        <div class="searchbar">
            <input  img src="image" type="search" id="autocomplete"  placeholder="Search..."/>
            <button class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

After the edit the results didn't show up.
Where should I start? Any help would be appricated

Comment: You're using a jQuery plugin to render those search results.  Did you check the plugin's documentation for how to customize the results being displayed?  Does it support what you're trying to do?  If not, then you'd have to use something that does or write your own.  Where exactly are you stuck?  Currently you don't appear to have made any attempt at all.

Comment: @David Thanks for your intresets, I will first do more digging and testing before asking a question

Answer (score 3):

## Edit

This function will extend the autocomplete functionality to render images with your search results.

```
 $.widget( "app.autocomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
        var result = this._super( ul, item );
        if ( item.image) {
            result.find( "a" )
                  .addClass( "ui-menu-item-icon" )
                  .css( "background-image", "url(" + item.image + ")" );
        }
        return result;
    }
});
```

In your source array, you could add a field called `image`. So an object might look like this:

```
{
  image: 'http://via.placeholder.com/15x15'
  value: 'bitcoin.html',
  label: 'Bitcoin (BTC)',
}
```

Then create an `img` element in your html (you didn't provide the html for the dropdown so i have no clue how you have it structured) and set the source to related image path.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I already tried to do that but it didn't work I have edited my question. Can you take a look at it

Comment: Unfortunately, your edit does not provide any clarity to your issue. Can you provide the HTML for the dropdown? Or information regarding the plug-in you are using?

Comment: Thanks for your intresets, I will first do more digging and testing before asking a question.